# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null on slider

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I have a slider which when the mouse move event is fired by it I want to display its value inside a paragraph.

This is the code I am using:

```
var exit = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var slide = document.getElementById('slider');
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    slide.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
    console.log(slide.value);
});
```

Html

```
<input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="10" id="slider">
<p></p>
```

My problem is that I get this error:

> "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to add an event listener for an `input` event not a `mousemove` event.

The `input` event fires when the range input changes value not when the mouse just happens to be moving over the range selector.

As pointed out by @Gersey, the `input` event will be fired when the user changes the value with the arrow keys.

Here is a demo that highlights the issue

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var slide = document.getElementById('slider'),
    p1 = document.querySelector('#oninput'),
    p2 = document.querySelector('#onmousemove');

  slide.addEventListener("input", function() {
    p1.textContent += ' ' + slide.value;
  });

  slide.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
    p2.textContent += ' ' + slide.value;
  });
};
```

```css
div.display {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="10" id="slider" />

<div>
  <div class="display" id="oninput"></div>
  <div class="display" id="onmousemove"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer! If I give the focus to the `<input>` and then move the slider with the keyboard arrows, with the *mousemove* event nothing happens while with the *input* event worsk.

Answer (score 0):

move the line

```
   var slide=document.getElementById('slider');
```

into your window load callback. The problem may be that the dom is not loaded when you init the slide, so its not there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this bro ..

```js
        var exit = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
        var slide = document.getElementById('slider');
        slide.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
          console.log(slide.value);
          $('p').text('value : '+slide.value);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="10" id="slider">
<p></p>
```